# How to set a context for xpath seach

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an ajax request to a sever which returns an html page like the following:\

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="name">
        <b>Name of the item</b>
    </div>

    <div class="itemProp">
        <input type="hidden" name="index" value="88">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which continues for as many items matched my request.
Now i want to be able to get the name of the item and the index value.

What have i done is :

```
var itemCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("div[@class ='item']");
foreach (var item in itemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name {0}",item.SelectSingleNode("//b").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine("rdef index {0}", item.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='index']").GetAttributeValue("value","Not Found"));
}
```

But i'm searching for the whole document for the tags, so it returns only the first one every time.

My Question is , how can i set a context to search from with Xpath and HtmlAgilityPack , so when i im the for loop , it will only serach for the b tag inside the item childrens and not the whole document .
Also if there is a better way to do this , im open to suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.//foo`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name {0}",item.SelectSingleNode(".//b").InnerText);
```

the same the for other relative paths as well, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("rdef index {0}", item.SelectSingleNode(".//input[@name='index']").GetAttributeValue("value","Not Found"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication63
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<Root>" +
                  "<div class=\"item\">" +
                    "<div class=\"name\">" +
                      "<b>Name of the item</b>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"itemProp\">" +
                      "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"88\"/>" +
                    "</div>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class=\"item\">" +
                    "<div class=\"name\">" +
                      "<b>Name of the item</b>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"itemProp\">" +
                      "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"88\"/>" +
                    "</div>" +
                  "</div>" +
                "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "div") && (x.Attribute("class") != null) && x.Attribute("class").Value == "item").Select(y => new {
                name = y.Descendants("b").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                value = y.Descendants("input").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```